# UpdatePanel trigger Method

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a drop down list that triggers an updatepanel when the index is changed.  Thats great and all, but I see it loads the update panel before running the drop down list control's even method. Is there a way i can tell it to run the controls event method, BEFORE loading the update panel? I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer is: **No**.  To the best of my knowledge, you can't change the firing order of ASP.NET's events during the page's life-cycle.  Usually, it's best to learn the events of the life-cycle and work around them.  [Here's an excellent diagram](http://blog.krisvandermast.com/content/binary/ASP.NET-2.0-life-cycle.png) of the life-cycle events.

Comment: And your program should never rely on the order of control events firing, which is stated specifically in the documentation.

Comment: Wow, I just realized I was following the logic completely wrong.  The link and then thinking about what womp said regard not relying on the firing order just made my brain click. You guys saved me hours of work. Thanks again!